# Access gridview row's data from LinkButton inside that row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Each row of the GridView is populated from a SQL DB.

Each row has a LinkButton that brings up a popup.

In the code behind I want to have access to the DataField="RCID"

I guess I'd like to attach the RCID field to the Upload link so when it's clicked I have access to the RCID within the function that handles the onclick.

How do I get this rows RCID?

```
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
            OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
            GridLines="Horizontal" AllowPaging="true" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="false">

            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="RCID" DataField="RCID" Visible="false"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="RC Type" DataField="RCType"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Channel" DataField="Channel"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Total" DataField="Total"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Expired In 30 Days" DataField="ExpiredIn30Days"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Expired In 60 Days" DataField="ExpiredIn60Days"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Expired In 90 Days" DataField="ExpiredIn90Days"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Last Updated" DataField="LastUpdated"></asp:BoundField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Management">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="Upload" Text="Upload" CommandName="Upload" ></asp:LinkButton> |
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="Details" Text="Details" CommandName="Details"></asp:LinkButton> |
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="Files" Text="Files" CommandName="Files"></asp:LinkButton> |
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="Edit" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit"></asp:LinkButton> |
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>


            </Columns>


        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution would be as follows:

1. Add RowCreated and RowCommand events for GridView
2. In RowCreated event, I have set “Visible” property to “false” for first column for both header and data row.
3. In RowCommand event, CommandName is checked first and then index for select command is retrieved. I have retrieved the row for that index and then retrieved the text in the specified row cell.

check this example:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
        }
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Select")
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];
            Label1.Text = (row.Cells[0].Text);
        }
    }
```

Second approach:
Assign command argument to your hidden field value. This will reduce another efforts. check this way:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action3" Visible="false">
 <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
 <ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkretqty" runat="server" Text="Return Qty" CommandName="RETQTY" ToolTip="Click here to Add Return Qty Entry"
 CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'>
</asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
Code Behind code

protected void gvsearch_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
 {
 try
 {
 if (e.CommandName == "SRCSELREC")
 {
Int32 rowind = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
string val = ((Label)gvgpitemdtl.Rows[rowind].FindControl("d")).Text.ToString();


 }
}
catch (Exception ex)
 {
 General.MessageBox(this.Page, "Error at Gridview Row Command : " + ex.Message.ToString());
 return;
 }
}
```

References:
[Way of getting Hidden column value in GridView](https://yasithl.wordpress.com/2010/09/05/way-of-getting-hidden-column-value-in-gridview/)
 [How to Get Hidden Column values in GridView](http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/06/22/faq-how-to-get-hidden-columns-value-in-gridview.aspx)
[To Find Control in GridView on RowCommand event in asp.net](https://keyurmehta.wordpress.com/2013/03/07/to-find-control-in-gridview-on-rowcommand-event-in-asp-net/)
[How to hide GridView column and retrieve value from hidden column cell in ASP.NET](http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/1410.html)

Answer (score 1):

Add `CommandArgument='<%# Eval("RCID") %>'` in the linkbutton's markup:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="Upload" Text="Upload" CommandName="Upload" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("RCID") %>'/>
```

Now, in the code behind of the handler, just read the `CommandArgument`property of the passed `GridViewCommandEventArgs` parameter:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Upload")
    {
        var valueOfRCID = e.CommandArgument;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mshsayem may be right but note you can also just grab the value from within the click event as follows

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="Upload" Text="Upload" OnClick="Upload_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("RCID") %>'/>

  protected void Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)(sender);
        string RCID = btn.CommandArgument;
    }
```